# How do I replace strings of a table from another table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I update/replace the value of the first table from the list of my second table in SQL. Sorry im not so good in using **replace()** of SQL especially replacing from values base from different table

First table.

```
ID | Value
======================
1 | Fruits[Apple]
2 | Fruits[Apple,Mango]
3 | Apple[Red,Green]
```

Second table

```
Search | Replace
=========================
Apple  | Orange
Green  | Yellow
```

Comment: Normalise your table life will be so much easier

Comment: This is the actual design.. the values are just set for example but the real data is more complicated to look at..

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of recursive replace.
something like a loop

```
declare @t1 table (ID int, Value varchar(max))
declare @t2 table (Search  varchar(max), ReplaceWith varchar(max))
insert @t1 values (1, 'Fruits[Apple]'),(2, 'Fruits[Apple,Mango]'), (3, 'Apple[Red,Green]')
insert @t2 values ('Apple', 'Orange'),('Green', 'Yellow')

--loop nth times for rows that have more than one match
while exists(select top 1 * from @t1 inner join @t2 on charindex(Search, Value ) > 0)
begin 
    update @t1
    set Value = replace(Value, Search, ReplaceWith)
    from @t2
    inner join @t1 on charindex(Search, Value ) > 0
end

select * from @t1
```

results

```
ID    Value
----- -----------------------
1     Fruits[Orange]
2     Fruits[Orange,Mango]
3     Orange[Red,Yellow]
```

Alternatively, you could use recursive [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
;with CTE(ID, Value, rec_count)
as (
    select distinct ID, Value, 1 as rec_count  from @t1 inner join @t2 on charindex(Search, Value ) > 0
    union all
    select ID, Value = replace(Value, Search, ReplaceWith), rec_count +1
    from CTE
    inner join @t2 on charindex(Search, Value ) > 0
)
update @t1 
set Value= replaced.Value 
from @t1 t
inner join 
( select distinct ID, Value 
  from CTE c 
  where rec_count > 1 
  and rec_count = (select max(rec_count) from CTE where ID = c.ID) ) replaced on replaced.ID = t.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use following `UPDATE` by cross-joined select statement and enjoy it! ;)

```
UPDATE  tFirst
SET     Value = REPLACE(tFirst.Value, tSecond.Search, tSecond.Replace)
FROM
    [First]             tFirst
    CROSS JOIN [Second] tSecond
```